# cos(nx) in p/q form using Memoization

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I want to calculate cos(nx) = p/q Using recursion and memoization so i tried Chebyshev Method for Recursive Method it works for small inputs of n but i want to do it for larger inputs like 10^18 etc. How should i approach it to calculate cos(nx) in p/q Form?
For larger Values of n i am getting Memory Problem How do i fix that?
cos(x) = a/b Known

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
map<long, long> numerator;
map<long, long> denominator;
#define MODULO 1000000007
long a, b, n;

int main() {
    cin >> a >> b;
    cin >> n;
    numerator[0] = 1;
    numerator[1] = a;
    denominator[0] = 1;
    denominator[1] = b;
    for (long i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        numerator[i] = (long) (2 * a * numerator[i - 1] - b*numerator[i - 2]) % MODULO;
        denominator[i] = (denominator[i - 1] * denominator[i - 2]) % MODULO;
    }
    cout << "numerator of cos(nx) = " << numerator[n] << " denominator = " << denominator[n] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] then edit your question to say where you are stuck and what errors are happening that you can't figure out on your own by learning to debug code.  SO is not a code-writing  service.

Comment: Don't ever do: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Ok Sir will remember that. Can u tell me how do i Improve my code?

Answer (score 0):

lol Thats a contests question you're asking for. Shame on you. That's Codechef's February Challenge's Question. How low can you fall for some rating. smh